# How to kill a currently long running query in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

How can I kill a currently long-running query in Neo4j (without restarting the server)?

I know we can globally [set a timeout for queries](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/5ec8FThLTeo), but sometimes I want to execute heavy queries/creates/updates on the server that could take a while...

Thanks.

Comment: That is planned in 2.x, we are right now structuring the code for having the concept of a request through all layers, among other in order to be able to kill it.

Comment: @PeterNeubauer :When will the first stable version of 2.0 should come out? and when specifically this feature will come out ?

Comment: Maybe, replace long-running query by many short-running? Can you write about your task here or to my e-mail?

Comment: @Eugeny: I know I can do that, but my question is about already running queries. I'm not the only developer so I can't control every cypher query that is being executed. besides, sometimes people make mistakes and I want to fix them without restarting the neo4j server.

Comment: You can to create plugin and execute each long-running query in new thread (and kill it when you want).

Comment: @Eugeny maybe you should write that up as the answer

Comment: @PeterNeubauer Now that 2.0 has been around for a bit, is there a way to accomplish this without writing a plugin?

Comment: Have a look at this forum post [https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/neo4j/5ec8FThLTeo]( https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/neo4j/5ec8FThLTeo)

Answer (score 11):

Available in version >3.1 Enterprise with

```
CALL dbms.listQueries()
CALL dbms.killQuery(queryId)
```

Admins may "kill'em all"

There is also

```
 :queries
```

Comment: I'm on 3.4.0. For some reason it doesn't cancel queries.

Comment: @expert  **Enterprise** version ?

Comment: @Jerome_B Yep, enterprise from their docker image

Comment: @expert in the browser, the loader keeps turning although I killed the query.
I verified with the movies dataset (:play movies) and this long running query 
 MATCH (n),(m),(o)
RETURN n,m,o

The icon must be clicked twice, and the second is not the cross.  A bit counterintuitive imho

Comment: @expert I verified with dbms.killQuery too. Works

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to abort queries in Neo4j. At least I haven't found anything when I needed and I searched the docs quite a lot of times.

Answer (score 1):

The 2.2 release has some functionality around this area, but still no monitoring tool that you could see, for example, the queries ran by other clients, you can only kill your own long running queries, executed through the web ui or the shell.

[Neo4J 2.2 Release Notes](http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-2-milestone-1-release/)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to abort queries in Neo4j.

There is a way to kill long running queries automatically with the
Guard stuff (you can pick either max number of operations or a timeout). There were some instructions sent out (couldn't find it immediately and I need to run).

Answer (score 0):

I found that in the shell pressing CTRL-C terminates the query (running V3.0.3)