# Can I abort (not timeout) a long running query in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

If my application initiates a long-running (minutes) query in Neo4j, can it be (programmatically) interrupted or aborted at my discretion - and without killing the server?

Searching the documentation and the web, it appears there is a “TIMEOUT” configuration; however, this does not satisfy my requirement to abort the query at my discretion (any time.)

In my application (and many others I would think?)  the user may change his mind and select some other feature that effectively requires a new query of the (large) graph, and makes the first query unnecessary.  We don’t want to leave that query running and consuming resources.  We also don’t want to lose other pending queries or have to restart the server.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056594/how-to-kill-a-currently-long-running-query-in-neo4j as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for aborting queries in Neo4j for the moment AFAIK